# Position of a vertical div on an horizontal div with database dates in Rails (timeline)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, algorithm

I would like to create kind of timeline (horizontal line: div) with some data coming from my database with a creation date. I would like to place kind of marker (vertical line) automatically on the timeline with this date.

The issue is this timeline is a div with a fix size (responsive but size in %) so when there is a new data on the timeline, the others has to resize. And for example, if I have three dates: 2009 -2010 -2045 of course there is more space between 2010 and 2045 than 2009 and 2010 ...

Do you have some advises / algorithm to do that please?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place them to scale, you can do something like:

```
totalTime = maxDate - minDate
for each date
    yPercentage = (maxDate - date) / totalTime
```

This will put the first date at the start, last date at the end, and others in between, proportionally.

Comment: Exact thanks, this was almost what I wanted, I just swap the calcul to have the last event at the end and the older at the begining: `for each date
    yPercentage = (date - minDate) / totalTime`